# In BottomSheetFragment When i clicked on EditText field then show disabled Softkeypad In android Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio

I mentioned my bottom sheet edit text code and image please help me! I do not understand what's going wrong with my code!

Softkeypad not working but visible with black light shadow

MY XML File

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".view.dashboard.home.FullPageBottomSheetFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/black_border"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="@string/search_friends"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search_icon"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewFriends"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="700dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My Fragment Code

```
public class FullPageBottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment/* implements TextWatcher*/ {
    private FragmentFullPageBottomSheetBinding binding;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewFriends; // Add this line 

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentFullPageBottomSheetBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        

        // Request focus to the EditText to show the soft keypad
        binding.textSearch.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        binding.textSearch.requestFocus();
//        binding.textSearch.addTextChangedListener(this);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

[image]

This type of error i seen first time in my carrer please help me for fix my code.

Comment: Is that on the emulator? or do you feel that on real devices?

Comment: yes, I tested on the real device this happened when I used TextWatcher.